# how to call global function in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have make two global function now i want to call them in my HTML page. i have make separate file for global function and calling them it into our HTML page but it seems that something wrong with my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    jQuery.functionOne = function () {
        var text = "i am first"
    };
    jQuery.functionTwo = function (param) {
        var text = "i am second"
    };
})(jQuery);
$('.first').text().functionOne();
$('.second').text().functionTwo();
</script>


<body>
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `.text()` **returns** a **string** and strings don't have a `functionOne` method by default. Maybe you have to **pass** the value to the function. How is it defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this please: If you are calling these functions within text function then try like the code below: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/SMLTP/ or http://jsfiddle.net/SMLTP/1/

**Update** demo according to your updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/SMLTP/8/

If you keen: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Hope this helps or please lemme know if I missed anything! `:)`

```
$('.first').text(function(){
    return functionOne();
});

$('.second').text(function(){
      return   functionTwo();
});
```

sample function =>

```
 $('.first').text(function(){
         return functionOne();
    });


function functionOne(){
    return "HULK is awesome";
}
​
```

**Update**

```
functionOne = function() {
    var text = "i am first"
    return text;
};

functionTwo = function() {
    var text = "i am second"
    return text
};

$('.first').text(function() {
    return functionOne();
});

$('.second').text(function() {
    return functionTwo();
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying on the post. i just edited on my code i have used namespace method can you please use my code and for explaining answer

Comment: @amit Done see here demo as per your question: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/SMLTP/8/ `:)` this will help.

Comment: sir why we use return. i mean if we have used return in functionOne why need to use it again or if we use it in .text(return functionOne) so why use into functionOne return text

Comment: Hey @amit lol < I aint Sir or I will be owning an airlines > `:))` now - if you are not returning a string to `functionOne` then it will have nothing in it. now `text` returns a string; and in the code `functionOne` need to return a string to set to somthing: i.e. in diagram I will show it like this: `functionOne` ===> **(Set as string)** ===> `.text` ==> (returns what `functionOne is set to) `:)` hope it makes it clear.?

Comment: @amit: You could also write `$('.first').text(functionOne())` or even `$('.first').text(functionOne)`.